# CV2 triangulatePoints() usage - Python OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration, stereo-3d, 3d-reconstruction

I am trying to reconstruct the scene's 3d points using two stereo images. Here is what I am doing so far:

- Calibrated both cameras using calibrateCamera(), then used stereoCalibrate() to get the Essential matrix.
- Used SIFT to get good matched features from both images of an object.
- Now I want to reconstruct the 3D points of that object using triangulatePoints(). I know that the matched features will be used as inputs, however, I am not sure what should the other inputs be (projection matrices) and where to get them?

Comment: The description in reference manual:
"Projections matrices can be obtained from stereoRectify."

Comment: Projection matrices are obtained from calibration. Images should have been previously corrected for distortion too.